# BibLatex: Entry in ToC either displays wrong page or links to wrong page

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, biber

In the following MWE, the Bibliography entry in the ToC links to page 3 instead of page 5, where the Bibliography is.

If I first `\printbibliography` and then `\addcontentsline`, then the entry in the ToC links to the last page of the Bibliography (this is kind of hard to put in the MWE, but see [this other question and the first response](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154740/wrong-page-number-of-references-in-toc-scrreprt)

(if I omit `\cleardoublepage`, then the ToC entry displays the wrong page and links to the wrong page)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{library.bib}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}

 \cite{Kullback1997}.
\blindtext
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the .bib file:

```
@Book{Kullback1997,
  Title                    = {Information Theory and Statistics},
  Author                   = {Kullback, S.},
  ISBN                     = {9780486696843},
  Publisher                = {Dover Publications},
  Series                   = {A Wiley publication in mathematical statistics},
  URL                      = {https://books.google.com.sa/books?id=05LwShwkhFYC},
  Year                     = {1997},
  __markedentry            = {[wolfersf:6]},
  Lccn                     = {97014382}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add a `\phantomsection` as anchor. But better is it to use the tools of biblatex:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}

 \cite{doody}.
\blindtext
%\cleardoublepage
%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```