# Bibliography link in TOC doesn't point to the bibliography (hyperref)

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

Every chapters and sections of my document within the TOC are pointing to the right places, except the bibliography.

How to fix that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,american]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Biblatex references:
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
style=authoryear
]
{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\setlength\bibitemsep{0.8\baselineskip}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}


\usepackage[
 unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,
 bookmarksnumbered=true,
 bookmarksopen=true,
 bookmarksopenlevel=1,
 breaklinks=false,
 pdfborder={0 0 1},
 backref=false,
 colorlinks=false
 ]
 {hyperref}

\hypersetup{
 colorlinks=false,
 linkbordercolor={0 0.8 0.2},
 linktoc=section
 }


\usepackage{minitoc}
\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{Contents of chapter\,:}
\mtcsetrules{*}{off}
\mtcsetoffset{minitoc}{-2.0em}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{gobble} 
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Table}

\title{Title}

\author{\normalsize{\textsc{Name} First Name}}
\date{\small{\today}}


\maketitle

\vspace*{-12mm}

\dominitoc

\tableofcontents  

\newpage{}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Figures list}
\listoffigures \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Figures list} \mtcaddchapter   

\newpage{}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tables list}
\listoftables \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Tables list} \mtcaddchapter 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage{}
\chapter*{Sumary}
\markboth{Sumary}{Sumary}
\addstarredchapter{Sumary}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\minitoc
stuff

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage{}
\chapter*{Introduction}
\markboth{Introduction}{Introduction}
\addstarredchapter{Introduction}
\minitoc
other stuff

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage{}
%\chapter*{Bibliography} % Test: if I un-comment this line, I got two "References" chapters then.
\markboth{References}{References}
\addstarredchapter{References}
\printbibliography%[]
\nocite{*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use it like this:

```
\printbibliography%[]
\markboth{References}{References}
\addstarredchapter{References}
```

Comment: So simple? I can't believe it...
Thanks.

Comment: The `\addstarredchapter` -command needs to be set _after_ `\printbibliography` otherwise hyperref will think it still belongs to your Introduction. Same behaviour as for labels. You're welcome!

Comment: I just see now that the page for the bibliography in the TOC is the last page of the bibliography, not the first one with this method. How to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

This won't work correctly as it print the last page for the bibliography in the TOC.

Instead, you have better to simply insert your bibliography like (it works with `biblatex`):

```
\printbibliography[title={References},heading=bibintoc]
\markboth{References}{References}
```

As explained here: [Bibliography not in ToC when using biblatex/biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67153/bibliography-not-in-toc-when-using-biblatex-biber)
or here: [Wrong page number of References in toc (scrreprt)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154740/wrong-page-number-of-references-in-toc-scrreprt)
for example.